# Gitlab 12.2.4 server hooks not firing

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I created a custom_hooks in the same directory as my projects hooks directory. I've named it correctly, made it executable, and owned by Git.

For some reason the hook never fires on commit or push.

How do I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized I need to use pre-receive hook and now it's working.